# Where is my ConnectionPool class?

Tags: java, jsp

Now I am working with one of old site that was written using JSP. I see that everywhere in the code used 
    `import ConnectionPool.ConnectionPool;`

And I see that CLASSPATH set as:
classpath=%classpath%;C:\j2sdkee1.3\lib\j2ee.jar;C:\Working\Application\MyApp\Bean;

Could you please help understand me where I can search ConnectionPool.class?

May be in C:\Working\Application\MyApp\Bean or in my application directory?

Example of using ConnectionPool in JSP:

```
<code>
<%@ page import="ConnectionPool.ConnectionPool;" %> 
<%
    application.removeAttribute("MYAPP_POOL");  
    ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool(); 
    pool.setDriver("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    pool.setURL("jdbc:odbc:myapp");
    pool.setUsername("Username");
    pool.setPassword("Password");
    pool.setSize(20);
    pool.initializePool();
    application.setAttribute("MYAPP_POOL",pool);
%>
</code>
```

Comment: Why do you care for the `*.class` file? Are you sure you're not really interested in the `*.java` file?

Comment: Also: You suggested `C:\Working\Application\MyApp\Bean`. Have you *tried* looking for it there?

Comment: I have not <code>*.java</code> or <code>*.jsp</code> file named ConnectionPool too. Unfortunately, this folder is currently not in my archives, I'm trying to get it now. Is it true I understand that this file should be there?

Comment: Then the used class is probably [`sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.ConnectionPool`](http://pag-www.gtisc.gatech.edu/conchord/examples/jdk/sun/jdbc/odbc/ee/ConnectionPool.java.html). It's not a file someone previously working on this project created, but rather comes from the JDK itself.

Comment: Thank you! So I just need to add a .jar file with this class to my classpath?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything since it's in the JDK. If something isn't working, please update the question and describe what isn't working and maybe show the potential exceptions + stacktrace you're receiving.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll update of my question tomorrow morning, when I'll get detaled information about exceptions and stacktrace.

Comment: Looking at your classpath, I see `C:\j2sdkee1.3\lib\j2ee.jar`. This sounds like you are using a *very* out-dated version of Java EE. I'm not much into Java's history, but maybe the `ConnectionPool` class didn't exist in there (did this ever work before or are you using such an old jdk on your machine only?). I'd also not recommend using such an old version, though upgrades can be tricky if the codebase is old and/or bad.

Comment: One more note: The ODBC bridge has been removed with Java 8.